# Outlook AddIn gives "AddIn element not found in XML" error on install

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, outlook, outlook-addin

I've created my first Outlook 2010 AddIn using VS 2012 but I'm having trouble creating a setup.exe.

I'm using clickOnce to publish the setup.exe files but when I try to install the AddIn, I get the same message as this guy - [Error deploying VSTO Office addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728794/problem-deploying-vsto-office-addin)

It turns out I cannot create MSI installer in VS2012 as written in the accepted SO answer because MS no longer supports it. Instead I am to use InstallShield to create the setup.exe. I tried that with the steps outlined in this video - http://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/demos/IS2010_VSLE_Demo/IS2010_VSLE_Demo-lite.html

That failed too. For some reason it cannot find the .vsto file which doesn't seem to get created! The file path it looks for is also wrong even though I did specify in the registry "[TARGETDIR]… |vstolocal" per the instructions from an MSDN page.

Question: What do I need to do to fix either the clickOnce installer error or the InstallShield error?

I don't care which deployment method I use as long as:
1. it WORKS!
2. I can copy the setup.exe (w/ any necessary files) on to a USB stick and give a few people to test the Outlook AddIn.

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody there??? Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Andy_mic in MSDN Forum, here's the answer:

Follow ALL the steps, step by step, in the following link: [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc442767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I ran into a couple of problems:

1. I did not have the GUI Generator installed as a windows program. See this post for solution: [Is Tools > Create GUID removed in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882434/is-tools-create-guid-removed-in-visual-studio-2012)
2. The value for the Manifest in the Registry data of the AddIn should be: "file:///[INSTALLDIR]ManifestFileName.vsto|vstolocal". In my case the manifest filename was ABCAddin_v1_0_0.vsto and so the value has to be "file:///[INSTALLDIR]ABCAddin_v1_0_0.vsto|vstolocal"
3. If you do not find the deployment and application manifest files in the "bin/release" folder, its because you need build a release version of the project first!

Comment: I have created Outlook Addin and in that `myproject.csproj` I am not able to get <SolutionID>. What can I do for get that ID?

Comment: Your question is different from mine. Please post it as a separate question on SO.